# Generic object -> object conversion for webapi

Tags: c#, json, json.net

This is a somewhat unique problem I think... I can solve it easily in js/ts but am kinda stuck trying to implement this in the c# solution if at all possible.

Keeping it simple, so as not to write a novel here, I'm trying to improve some crappy json serialization.  It's using dictionaries within dictionaries currently and it's assy to parse in JS.  I wrote a TS library that "unpacks" the data into a more palatable format, but I'd love to move that server-side.  The model is an xml object with elements unkown to the application (because it's defined in a CMS and can be modified any time even while the app is running) and because Vendor, I'm stuck with c#.

Super easy in JS - c#'s strong typing is killing me here.

How would you create this addKvp function in c# (where element would be of type object, i assume)

```
function addKvp (element, key, value) { element[key] = value; }

var abc = {};
addKvp(abc, "foo", "bar");
console.log(abc.foo);
```

where "key" is not a member of element.... *yet*.

The other directions I could tackle this from is maybe by manipulating the json serialization somehow or putting my typescript library that does exactly this in a node express server and have it sit between the two - but this'd be the "simplest" solve, if it is possible.  It feels very against the c# grain.

Comment: Are you using Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json for manipulating JSON?

Comment: Newtonsoft currently - I have control tho and it's the only thing this project does, so I can implement whatever

Comment: You could use `JObject` for `abc` and add `value` using `JToken.FromObject()` , i.e. `element[key] = JToken.FromObject(value);`.  Or you could use `ExpandoObject` for `abc`, i.e. `dynamic abc = new ExpandoObject()`.

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

If you have this problem and are using NewtonSoft, there's an object in Newtonsoft.Json.Linq called "JObject" which behaves *almost exactly* like I was wanting.

For simple explanation, my sample js function would be written as...

```
void AddKvp(JObject element, string key, (whatever type) value)
{
 element[key] = value;
 //doesn't seem to be able to convert <T> values on its own and this is just a sample so i'm not gonna bother figuring it out
}
```